# js code shows error after creating new instance of object

Tags: javascript

When I create new instance of ClickEvent object it returns following error. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/np86y/) for jsfiddle code. Below is my code

```
var ClickEvent = function (event) {
    this.ev = $('.' + event);
    this.ev.on('click', this.userInput());
};

ClickEvent.protoype = function () {
    return {
        userInput: function () {
            console.log('user');
        },

        show: function () {
            console.log('show');
        }
    };   
}();

var c = new ClickEvent('event');
    c.show();
```

Why does it show this error and how can I solve it?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'userInput'
```

Comment: That's not your real code. For a start, you spelt `prototype` wrong. _[edit: Oh god, it **is** your real code...]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

1. You have a typo in `prototype`.
2. `this.ev.on('click', this.userInput());` should be `this.ev.on('click', this.userInput);` - you want to pass a reference to the function so it's executed when the user clicks, you don't want to call it when binding the event handler.

Comment: +1: No live demo but your answer is constructed better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You spelt `prototype` wrong; [your code otherwise executes fine](http://jsfiddle.net/JEmYG/), though you meant to reference the method with `this.userInput` rather than invoking it right away with `this.userInput()`, and due to this you get both messages `'show'` and `'user'` when the page loads.

With those fixes in place, your code [functions as I expect you intend](http://jsfiddle.net/UVU5W/): the `'user'` only appears when you click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that no where in the javascript library, a method userInput can be found. Which I can tell is very likely since you have not referenced the userInput variable anywhere before line 3. Also the .on() has two parameters: ("EVENT", "FUNCTION"). In your code, this.userInput is not a function and cannot function as one.

Comment: This is a basic idea:
    $('.event').on('click', function(){
        alert("Hi there!");
    });

Comment: Well, it _is_ a function. He should have written `this.userInput` not `this.userInput()`, but that wouldn't cause _this_ error message. Also, which line something is written on is not entirely relevant.

Answer (score -1):

fixed Type, and a little change , this works.

```
function ClickEvent(event) {
    this.ev = $('.' + event);
    this.ev.on('click', this.userInput());
};

ClickEvent.prototype = {
    userInput: function () {
        console.log('user');
    },

    show: function () {
        console.log('show');
    }
};

var c = new ClickEvent('event');
c.show();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It displays both `show` and `user` when the page loads, without waiting for a user click.

Comment: No, it's because you wrote `this.userInput()` rather than `this.userInput`. Read the other answers.